# How can I prevent my website from rendering in quirks mode from some servers?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008

I have QA and Production environments for a website application.

- QA operating system: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise
- Production operating system: Windows Server 2008 Enterprise
- Client browser: IE9

I know that it is not ideal to use different OSs for QA and produuction, but this is the environment I have to work with because of my client's IT department. For some reason when the website is hosted on the QA server the pages seem to be rendered in quirks mode, but not on the production server. How can I prevent my website from rendering in quirks mode from the QA server? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the layout of the webpage. I changed the CSS for the layout and now it works when served from both servers. I still don't know why one of the servers rendered the content in quirks mode but the workaround is functioning well so all is good. Cheers.